# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' while git checkout

Tags: bash, git, git-branch, git-checkout

I Accidentally created a git branch, which contain '()' in branch name. I didn't get any error while creating the branch. But when i tried to **git checkout** to the branch from master, i got the following error.

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I tried renaming the branch with **git branch -m** and **git branch -m -f** but both commands returned the same error as given above.

How can i solve this situation ? Is there any method to get the changes i made in that branch??

Thanks in advance

Comment: `git checkout branch\(_name` -> escape the `(`.

Comment: `git checkout 'branch(_name)'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `git checkout "branchname"`

example If branchname is `abcd()`

```
git checkout "abcd()"
```